# Mongorestore "auth fails" at deployed app at meteor.com

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteorite

I received the information from my deployed app by using the command

meteor mongo -url bhedir.meteor.com

I then took the response and used the info for my 
mongorestore -u client -p meteorinfo - h meteorinfo -d bhedir_meteor_com meteordump/meteor

however, I keep getting the following error:

assertion: 18 { code: 18, ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth fails" }

I should note that I have several meteorite packages included but I don't see how that would affect this.

Also, I've done this before, granted not that many times, but did not run into any issues.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume 'meteorinfo' is a placeholder for the hostname and password you get out?

If so then when you get the auth info with meteor `mongo -url bhedir.meteor.com` you have to be very quick to do the mongorestore as the auth data you get only lasts 1 minute, then it expires and you have to do the `meteor mongo --url bhedir.meteor.com` call again

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some required parameter as might be the username, password or db