# Can mongorestore take a single url argument instead of separate arguments?

Tags: mongodb, url, meteor, mongorestore, database

If I have a mongo database URL of the following format

```
mongodb://someUsername:somePassword@some.server.com:27017/some_collection
```

Is there an easy way to give this to `mongorestore` without having to do

```
mongorestore -u someUsername -p somePassword -h some.server.com:27017 -db some_collection /path/to/dump
```

The reason I ask is because `meteor mongo --url` gives back a url of that form (and it looks like a standardized url format) but it [expires in one minute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18155648/586086). Because the password and host can be pretty long, it's hit or miss whether I can copy the parameters over (correctly) in one minute, and usually requires several tries.

Does something like the following exist?

```
mongorestore --url blah_blah /path/to/dump
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/15865565/586086

Comment: this is the most annoying thing, no consistency between different interfaces. If a url works for one interface, it should work for another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't find a way to pass the URL as a parameter but I wrote a one line command that converts the url into mongorestore parameters:

```
CMD=`meteor mongo -U autocomplete.meteor.com | tail -1 | sed 's_mongodb://\([a-z0-9\-]*\):\([a-f0-9\-]*\)@\(.*\)/\(.*\)_mongorestore -u \1 -p \2 -h \3 -d \4_'`
$CMD /path/to/dump
```

Comment: I updated your answer because the username generation has changed for Meteor. For reference, my script is at https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete/blob/master/examples/pubsublocal/upload-db.sh

Answer (score 2):

Update since five years ago:

Beginning with version 3.4.6, `mongorestore` accepts a URI argument:

> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#options