# Mongorestore, from meteor production server to local

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodump, mongorestore

I've found plenty of good instructions on how to use mongodump and mongorestore, to back up my meteor production server and restore the backup if need be:

```
meteor mongo --url myApp.meteor.com

mongodump -u client -h production-db-b2.meteor.io:27017 -d myApp_meteor_com -out dump/2014_10_21 -p [password from meteor mongo --url]

mongorestore -u client -h production-db-b2.meteor.io:27017 -d myApp_meteor_com dump/2014_10_21_v2/myApp_meteor_com -p [password from meteor mongo --url]
```

What I haven't found is an explanation of is how to restore a backup-dump *to* my local meteor app. I have a mongodump output in my app folder. I'm not sure if I can use mongorestore or if there's something else I'm supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 39):

The easiest way that I found:

1. `cd` in your project and execute `meteor` command
2. in another terminal:

`mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor dump/meteor`

change `127.0.0.1` if your localhost has different ip address and `3001` to a port you have mongodb on (it is usually `3001` or `3002`, so try both), `dump/meteor` is the path to a dump you created previously.

Also the easiest way to export local db:

1. `cd` in your project and execute `meteor` command
2. In another terminal:

`mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor`

again, change localhost ip and port if needed. . As a result, the dump/meteor folder with db files will be created in the folder you `cd` before running `mongodump`.

Good luck.

Comment: Just to add, if you don't have mongo installed on your mac, you can do this: ````brew install mongo````

Comment: Check out the port number, Your local meteor application is using — it is located in file `.meteor/local/db/METEOR-PORT`.

Answer (score 6):

To accomplish the opposite, sending local app data to production app, I wrote this little shell script. It has been useful while I am developing locally and just getting the demo synced for the client to view. Note it has `--drop` at the end which will overwrite your production database, use with care!

It takes care of the client, pw, and server data from `meteor mongo --url ...` which expires after 1 minute and is really annoying to try to copy-paste within that time.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mongodump -h 127.0.0.1:3001 -d meteor -o ~/www/APPNAME/server/dump
IN=`meteor mongo --url APPNAME.meteor.com`
client=`echo $IN | awk -F'mongodb://' '{print $2}' | awk -F':' '{print $1}'`
echo $client
pw=`echo $IN | awk -F':' '{print $3}' | awk -F'@' '{print $1}'`
echo $pw
serv=`echo $IN | awk -F'@' '{print $2}' | awk -F'/' '{print $1}'`
echo $serv
mongorestore -u $client -h $serv -d APPNAME_meteor_com dump/meteor -p $pw --drop
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what I do:

I. Create a mongo dump in the server

```
    DATE=$(date +%m%d%y_%H.%M);
    mongodump --host localhost -d APPNAME -o /tmp/APPNAME_$DATE 
    tar -cjvvf /tmp/APPNAME_$DATE.tar.bz2 /tmp/APPNAME_$DATE
```

II. Download the dump in the development machine and unpack in /tmp

```
    scp root@$HOST:/tmp/APPNAME_$DATE.tar.bz2 /tmp/
    cp /tmp/APPNAME_$DATE.tar.bz2 .
    mkdir -p /tmp/APPNAME_$DATE 
    cd /tmp/APPNAME_$DATE 
    tar -xjvf /tmp/APPNAME_$DATE.tar.bz2
```

III. Update local meteor development database

```
    mongorestore --db meteor  -h localhost --port 8082 --drop /tmp/APPNAME_$DATE/tmp/APPNAME_$DATE/APPNAME
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mongorestore`.

It's pretty much the same as what you already did.

In your first line: `meteor mongo --url myApp.meteor.com` just remove the last part to so the line will read: `meteor mongo --url`. 
When executed on your local machine you will get the information for the local instance of your meteor app. From that point you can just use `mongorestore` to restore your local db the way you already did remotely.

I use to do a `meteor reset` prior to a mongorestore, just to be sure that my db is empty, but I don't know if it's actual necessary.

Note that the app should be running when doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a script to download the meteor database. Check it out at https://github.com/AlexeyMK/meteor-download

Usage (in your app's root):

```
curl https://raw.github.com/AlexeyMK/meteor-download/master/download.sh > download.sh        
./download.sh yourapp.meteor.com`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Google Cloud for Meteor hosting, and wrote custom scripts.

I have this running on a cronjob to backup to google cloud storage:

https://github.com/markoshust/mongo-docker-backup-gcloud/blob/master/mongobackup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
MONGO_DB=dbname
MONGO_HOST=127.0.0.1
HOST_DIR=/home/YOURNAME
BACKUP_DIR=/mongobackup
BUCKET=gs://BUCKET_NAME
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`

/usr/bin/docker run --rm \
  -v $HOST_DIR/$BACKUP_DIR:$BACKUP_DIR \
  markoshust/mongoclient \
  mongodump --host $MONGO_HOST --db $MONGO_DB --out $BACKUP_DIR

sudo mkdir -p $HOST_DIR/$BACKUP_DIR/$MONGO_DB/$DATE
sudo mv $HOST_DIR/$BACKUP_DIR/$MONGO_DB/* $HOST_DIR/$BACKUP_DIR/$MONGO_DB/$DATE

$HOST_DIR/gsutil/gsutil rsync -r $HOST_DIR/$BACKUP_DIR $BUCKET

sudo /bin/rm -rf $HOST_DIR/$BACKUP_DIR
```

Then to restore locally, I created another script which downloads the backup from google cloud storage, stores locally, then does a local restore:

https://github.com/markoshust/mongorestore.sh/blob/master/.mongorestore.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
## This script syncs a mongodb backup from a Google Cloud Storage bucket and
## mongorestore's it to a local db.
##
## Author: Mark Shust <mark@shust.com>
## Version: 1.1.0

BUCKET=my-bucket-name
FOLDER=folder-name/$1
BACKUP_DIR=./.backups/
DB_NAME=localdb
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=27017

if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo 'Please specify a subdirectory to sync from...'
  exit 0
fi

mkdir -p $BACKUP_DIR

if [ ! -d $BACKUP_DIR ]; then
  gsutil -m cp -r gs://$BUCKET/$FOLDER $BACKUP_DIR
fi

mongorestore --db $DB_NAME -h $DB_HOST --port $DB_PORT --drop $BACKUP_DIR/$1/

echo 'Database restore complete.'
```

I have this working with Meteor, stupid simple and works great :) Just switch db name to `meteor` and port to `3001` (or whatever config you have). It's meteor-agnostic so works with any mongodb host/platform.