# Mongorestore command not found with meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Ok guys I receive a bunch of files of a `mongodb` (`.bson` and `.json`) I want to replace my current `meteor mongodb`, I have read al this post about it:

- [meteor: how can I backup my mongo database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816860/meteor-how-can-i-backup-my-mongo-database)
- [Mongorestore, from meteor production server to local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505543/mongorestore-from-meteor-production-server-to-local)
- [Restore a mongodb in meteor production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687404/restore-a-mongodb-in-meteor-production-server)
- [MongoDB: mongorestore: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041337/mongodb-mongorestore-command-not-found) (this actually have nothing to do with my problem)

and I end writing in my terminal while meteor app was running

`mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1:3001 --port 3001 -d meteor ~/Github/mongo/mongoDBRESTORE/admin/`

[image]

but the problem its that terminal output is `not command found`

does anybody know what Im doing wrong, what its the right way to do this?

Comment: Do you have mongo 2.6 installed on your machine separately from Meteor? `mongorestore` comes from Mongo's binaries which may not be bundled with Meteor.

Comment: mmmmm yes I think this was the reason I end doing something like `~/mongodb/bin/mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1:3001 -db meteor ~/Github/mongo/mongoDBRESTORE/admin`

Comment: You have to install mongo tool  `apt-get install mongo-tools` to run mongorestore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @rgoomar pointed in the comments I need to download https://www.mongodb.org/downloads the mongodb `bin` files then I simple **execute** `~/mongodb/bin/mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1:3001 -db meteor ~/Github/mongo/mongoDBRESTORE/admin`

and worked!